# is there any max limit for no:of rows while using sqlite?

Tags: android

I have a CSV file which contains around 1200 rows. I was trying to insert it into sqlite db. Around 300 rows only got inserted. Rest didnt...Is there any max limit on no:of rows in a table while using sqlite?

Comment: may be you should find answer on [this](http://old.nabble.com/rows-limit-td23119629.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya.. we can have more than 10000 inserts.. Please refer this [link](http://old.nabble.com/rows-limit-td23119629.html)

Answer (score 2):

I tried more than 10000 inserts it worked, also check in android market there is SQL performance check tool which makes more inserts.

Rgds
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

There IS a max limit for creating rows in SQLite.

> If the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used. If the
>   largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer
>   (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive
>   candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously
>   used. If no unused ROWID can be found after a reasonable number of
>   attempts, the insert operation fails with an SQLITE_FULL error.

check the [official SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) about Auto Increment.